# Access android emulator IP address from other

Tags: android, port, local, httpserver

I tried to create a http server on my android. The APK works fine on my real device. I get the IP address by this:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {

    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();

    while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {

        InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

        if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
            ip += "SiteLocalAddress: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It works on my real device. On the browser I can access to it by entering the IP got above (like 192.168.1.21:8888)

But if I run the code on my emulator. It shows more IP, some of them is like MAC address, and some of them is like normal address (but they are different): Like

> 192.168.232.2

and

> 192.168.200.2:8888

Then I tried to access both on the browser but after a while loading, it shows error  "This site can’t be reached".

I tried forwarding port by `adb forward tcp:8888 tcp:8888` but no luck. I also tried `10.0.2.2:8888` but maybe it's wrong be cause it's like forwarding from emulator to the local PC, not vice versa... So... what did I do wrong?

Thank you for your time

EDIT: After checking Resource Monitor, port 8888 is currently adb.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's cleaner but the IP got from there still not accessible. One more thing, after checking Resource Monitor. port 8888 is currently running adb